# Cannot find module from @aws-sdk when using es2020

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, tsconfig

I have changed tsconfig target to ES2020. But the problem I have now is that compiler does not see anything that is imported with "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.48.0";

```
Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?ts(2792)
```

When I don't use ES2020 it is easily seen. How can I fix that so that that package is seen again with ES2020 ?

tsconfig:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 14",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "target": "ES2020",    
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the answer - you just need to add moduleResolution: node